# Keycloak version and quarkus version mismatch during mvn package

Tags: java, maven, keycloak, quarkus

I succesfully build Keycloak 20.0.1 with quarkus.version 2.13.3.Final, but now I want to try with keycloak 22.0.5 and the `mvn clean package` command fails with:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.13.3.Final:build (default) on project keycloak: Execution default of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.13.3.Final:build failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.13.3.Final:build: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.jboss.jandex.DotName org.jboss.jandex.DotName.createSimple(java.lang.Class)'`

What I did to try and solve this in play with versioning in my pom. I tried quarkus version `3.2.8.Final` and the latest of final 3.1.x and 3.0.x. All failed with the same error. Below is first the child pom which fails with the error and the parent 2nd.

I have placed both poms in, but I am most curious in how to tackle this problem in the future, because what I tried was to look on the keycloak github and see what quarkus version is used there in the pom, but this did worked neither

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Keycloak Distribution -->
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-quarkus-dist</artifactId>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Keycloak Quarkus Server Libraries-->
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-quarkus-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>keycloak-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>keycloak-config-test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>keycloak</module>
    <module>java-config</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <!-- Java -->
    <java.version>17</java.version>

    <!-- Maven -->
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.2.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven.shade.plugin.version>3.5.1</maven.shade.plugin.version>
    <maven.jar.plugin.version>3.2.2</maven.jar.plugin.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>

    <!-- Project specific -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Keycloak -->
    <keycloak.version>22.0.5</keycloak.version>
    <quarkus.version>2.13.3.Final</quarkus.version>
    <quarkus.native.builder-image>mutable-jar</quarkus.native.builder-image>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <build-helper-maven-plugin.version>3.4.0</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--Quarkus-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus.arc</groupId>
            <artifactId>arc</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--keycloak-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-quarkus-server</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-quarkus-dist</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--REST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-keycloak-server-distribution</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>keycloak-quarkus-dist</artifactId>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <excludes>**/lib/**</excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>keycloak</finalName>
                    <buildDir>${project.build.directory}/keycloak-${keycloak.version}</buildDir>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `io.smallrye:jandex` latest dependency to **pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

This has the method `org.jboss.jandex.DotName.createSimple(Class<?> clazz)` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had added the missing jandex lib as mentioned above

next I also got an exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported api 524288

Started to investigate into the quarkus maven plugin which builds the jar and just removed it and stick to the apache maven plugin and this build the jar without a problem....

So not an anwer to the problem, but a solid workaround I believe.